# Prove that $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}},f_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $f_n(x)=\frac{n+1}{n}x$ is uniformly convergent.

Tags: real-analysis

Maybe the Statement of the Question is also false, I am trying to come up with an easy example for uniform convergence.

It is clear that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=$id,id$(x)=x$
To Show that the functionsequence is uniformly convergent I have to show

$\forall\epsilon>0\forall x\in \mathbb{R} \exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}\forall n \geq n_0:|\frac{n}{n+1}x-x|<\epsilon\iff |-\frac{1}{n+1}x|<\epsilon$

Now if I I Claim that I have found such a $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ If I would pick an $\epsilon>1$ and $x=n_0+1$ I would get $1<1$

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to come up with an easy example for uniform convergence.

It is very hard for a sequence of polynomials to converge uniformly on all of $\mathbb{R}$. Because all non-constant polynomials go to $\pm\infty$ at $\pm\infty$, a sequence of polynomials $p_n(x)$ can converge uniformly to $p(x)$ if and only if there is some $N$ such that $p_n(x)-p(x)$ is a constant for each $n>N$, and these constants go to zero. It isn't good enough to have the polynomial's coefficients converge - we need everything but the constant term to be equal after some point.

So, two options. Either we run the whole thing on some smaller interval, or we use examples that aren't polynomials. Here's one: $f_n(x)=\frac1{(x+\frac1n)^2+1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $|f_n(n)-f(n)| = 1$ for all $n$. Hence the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: Okey so the uniform convergence is a Statement About the sequence of functions but not About the limesfunction itself.

Comment: @RM777: I don't understand what you mean by limesfunction...

Answer (score 0):

Your second last line;

$|x|(\frac{n_0+1}{n_0}-1)= |x|\frac{1}{n_0} < \epsilon$.

Let $\epsilon =1$, and choose $x =n_0+1$.

$1>1$; Contradiction .